# jekyll-sass-converter not working

Tags: css, sass, jekyll, github-pages

I'm french, sorry for my english, I have a problem with Jekyll

I installed gems: jekyll, jekyll-sass-converter

But Jekyll dont convers styles.scss to styles.css

> I declared the styles on _includes/head.html:

```
 <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}css/styles.css">
```

**Assets was declared on _config.yml:**

```
sass:
  sass_dir: _lib
  style: compressed
```

**styles.scss output**

```
// Imports
@import "base";
@import "main";
```

**_lib folder output**

```
/base.scss
/main.scss
```

Github Project: https://github.com/micaelandre/micaelandre.github.io

Github Issue: https://github.com/micaelandre/micaelandre.github.io/issues/1

Website: https://micaelandre.github.io

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jekyll only convert sass files if the **.scss** starts with two lines of triple dashes, so in `css/styles.scss`:

```
---
---

// Imports
@import "base";
```

This will generate: `css/styles.css`.

Also note that you don't need to explicitely install the sass converter, as it is one of the jekyll gem [dependency](https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll).